# WP7 - Is it possible to automatically launch the camera capture without a button press?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, camera

I'm using this code to grab barcodes from the camera:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2011/11/07/wp7-real-time-video-scan-a-barcode-qr-code-in-your-app-using-zxing-lib.aspx

It works fine if it is called from a button press, but if you put it in page load nothing happens, I assume this is a security feature?

Is there any way around it?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code. All must be Ok with `Loaded` event. Maybe you put code inside constructor instead?

Comment: Yeah that was it thanks, just didn't work in the constructor, needed to be fully loaded. Did you want to add that as an answer so I can rate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All must be Ok with `Loaded` event. Maybe you put code inside constructor instead...